# clion wont compile, /bin/sh: python: command not found on mac

Tags: clion, vcpkg

I have a feeling its something to do with `vcpkg` library I'm using. Nevertheless, I have to figure out how to add python alias to SH. I managed to add it to zsh, but it turns out that is not what `Clion` wants...

Most of answers I find is about adding alias to bash, but I want SH...
How can I add python to Sh alias/path/environment on MAC?

Comment: On mac, `sh` is provided by Bash.

Comment: So it is bash then that I need to edit. hhhhh I though I need sh stuff. thanks! will google there.

Comment: Normally you would set an appropriate PATH either in the IDE or in whatever invokes the IDE (such as the graphical session), and any invoked shells would inherit that. You would generally not try to configure each shell.

Answer (score 1):

make a symbolic link from your python PATH to it

```
sudo ln -s <python PATH> <bin PATH>
```

for example:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: I'm still struggling with this, I've put mac on a side for few weeks hoping a patch would come out but sadly no luck, and this command gives me error.  ```sudo ln -s </usr/local/bin/python3> <sh>
zsh: parse error near `<'
```

Comment: You have to change <python PATH> to the PATH to your python command, I use brew so for example: `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3` the same for <sh> change to `/usr/local/bin`